# Closed form of $n!\sum_{k=3}^{n-1}{{n-2}\choose{k-1}}$

Tags: binomial-coefficients, factorial, closed-form

$n$ is given, and it takes part in the following formula.
$$n!\sum_{k=3}^{n-1}{{n-2}\choose{k-1}}$$

Is there a nicer way for expressing it? Without the summation sign?

Comment: Hint: $\sum_{k=0}^n {n \choose k} = 2^n$

Comment: Hint: the last term in the sum is $n-2$, so all you have to do to obtain the binomial identity for $2^{n-2}$ is to add the terms for $k=1$ and $k=2$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Consider the binomial expansion of $(1+1)^{n-2}$.